# How to assign a span to a certain username

Tags: php, html, append

### A Solution has been found! Thank you to @northkildonan and @Doug Leary.

---

Solution Code;

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 // output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<li class='list-group-item'>" . $row["user_name"];
if ($row["user_name"] == "TacoLover22") {
     echo "<span class='badge'>Dev</span>";
}
echo "</li>";
 }
```

##

I have a list of usernames and I have a code that checks if a username exists, if it does exist, I want a div to be appended to it. [Here's an image explaining this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvCrQ.jpg)

However, the code I have works, but it doesn't assign that div to the selected username.

Here's the PHP Code;

```
<?php 

if (
    $row["user_name"] === "TacoLover22");{
    echo  "<span class='badge'>Dev</span>";
    }
?>
```

here's the other php code that grabs all the usernames;

```
<?php
$servername = "####";
$username = "####";
$password = "########";
$dbname = "########";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT user_name FROM users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<li class='list-group-item'>" . $row["user_name"];
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

The result of this code can be found [here.](http://social.minecraft.uk.to/members/)

EDIT: Here's the full code from suggestions, it still doesn't seem to work. The span doesn't appear now.

```
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<li class='list-group-item'>" . $row["user_name"];
if ($row["user_name"] === "TacoLover22") {
     echo "<span class='badge'>Dev</span>";
}
echo "</li>";
}
```

Thanks for all and any help.

Comment: What happens if you change `===` to just `==`?

Comment: @Darren Nothing. It stays the same.

Comment: You should also remove the comma (`;`) behind your if statement ;) (`if ($row["user_name"] === "TacoLover22"); { <<<< That one`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to append the `<span>` inside your mysql-fetch-loop (note: you are talking about divs, but you are using a span, which is something different in html).

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<li class='list-group-item'>" . $row["user_name"];
    if ($row["user_name"] == "TacoLover22")
    {
        echo  "<span class='badge'>Dev</span>";
    }
}
```

**explanation:** you are iterating the resultset of your mysql-query right in your while-loop. the variable `$row` is your pointer which points to the respective row of your result.
after your while-loop is finished, your "pointer" will always show to the last result row of your mysql-query. so `$row["user_name"]` will always be set to the last user name found in your database. that's why you have to access it inside the while-loop.

**how to handle multiple users (as requested):**
I decided to use `switch` instead of `if elseif` statements here since it's better to read and less to write imho:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<li class='list-group-item'>" . $row["user_name"];

    switch($row["user_name"])
    {
        case "TacoLover22":
            echo "<span class='badge'>Dev</span>";
        break;
        case "AnotherUser":
            echo "<span class='badge'>User</span>";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MyNameIsNotSoCool i just changed the comparison operator from `===` to `==` as you don't wanna check for equality and same datatype, i guess. if you are still getting no span-output, then you don't have a user which is called (exactly!) "TacoLover22" in your database-table.

Comment: Thank you! I have managed to get it working, it turned out that I had duplicated code! Thanks again.

Comment: @MyNameIsNotSoCool i'll update my question in a second.

Comment: thanks, I've come up with another solution just before you posted the update, I have added a new row to my database and now I check if the person is a "Dev". Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I think this will do it:

```
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<li class='list-group-item'>" . $row["user_name"];
    if ($row["user_name"] === "TacoLover22") {
         echo "<span class='badge'>Dev</span>";
    }
    echo "</li>";
}
```

Comment: @MyNameIsNotSoCool it's a `span` not a `div`

Comment: northkildonan is right about the == vs ===, but do the right thing and also close your <li> tag as I suggested.

Comment: @DougLeary according to w3c you don't need the end-tag here: "An li element's end tag may be omitted if the li element is immediately followed by another li element or if there is no more content in the parent element." source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags

Comment: @northkildonan - yes, that's why I said "do the right thing" instead of "conform to the standard". Call me old fashioned but I think attribute values should be quoted and tags should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

assuming u are using sqli extention
the column user_username is list of special users, otherwise you will need 2 tables, 1 table to store users, and 1 auxiliar table to store special users

```
//query
$sql = "SELECT user_name FROM users";
//send to mysql, get result 
$sendquery = $conn->query($sql);
//fetch results as array
while ($result=$sendquery->fetch_array) {
  echo 'username:' . $result['user_name'] . '<span class='badge'>Dev</span>';
}
```

but your question is confusing, you should use 2 tables if you are having different type of users

```
TABLE USERS user_id | name | dev_id | email | password | ...
TABLE DEVS dev_id | name | level | access | ....

SQL query, using LEFT JOIN

SELECT 
    usern.name as username, dev.name as devname
FROM USERS as user
LEFT JOIN DEVS as dev
USING dev_id

php output use $result['devname']
```

$result['']
if you only neeed "TacoLover22" to display, in case thats the only person you need to add something, add a IF in the while cycle

```
//query
$sql = "SELECT user_name FROM users";
//send to mysql, get result 
$sendquery = $conn->query($sql);
//fetch results as array
while ($result=$sendquery->fetch_array) {
    if ($result['user_name'] == "TacoLover22") {
        echo 'username:' . $result['user_name'] . '<span class='badge'>Dev</span>';
}
    else {
        echo $result['user_name'];
    }
}
```